# Add click event on menu item

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

I am using bottom navigation bar, so I used three menu item in bottom navigation bar, my question is that I want to add some click eventon that button so when a user click on home button, it will come to the main activity from any activity and when user click on search bar, it will get a floating search bar in the bottom.

[image]

Comment: By looking at your design, it should use `Fragment` not `Activity`

Comment: Image link is there: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BxpsVv2fIBVrUEdNd0k0bk9PWEU

Comment: Do you have any code to show?

Comment: code is there. https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BxpsVv2fIBVrR2tTS3RKU2hHMTA

Answer (score 4):

Put this code in onCreate() of your activity

```
    BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = (BottomNavigationView)findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);

    bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.home:
                //Add your action onClick
                break;
            case R.id.search:

                break;

            case R.id.favorite:

                break;
            }
        return false;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the tutorial teach you add bottom navigation bar step by step.

see :[blog_iamsuleiman](http://blog.iamsuleiman.com/bottom-navigation-bar-android-tutorial/)